# Store JSON data into variable from URL in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I tried to store the JSON data into a variable in node from JSON file which is located at https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wwmu-gmzc.json Tell me what can I do for that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need a REST client library (hint: search `npm`), do GET call to that Url and store the result into a variable.

Comment: Post the code you used. We can help you with the code you've written, not write it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `mongoose` npm to save data to mongodb database
- use `request` npm to make http request to url

Make Model :

```
  var mongoose =require('mongoose')  
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var movieSchema = new Schema({
         actor_1: String,
         actor_2: String,
         actor_3:  String,
         director: String,
         locations: String,
         production_company:  String,
         release_year: String,
         title:  String,
         writer: String,
  });

 var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

in your app.js

```
 var request = require('request');
    var data=[];
    request('https://data.sfgov.org/resource/wwmu-gmzc.json', function(error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error);
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
        console.log('body:', body);
        if(response && response.statusCode==200){
        var data=body;
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
             var movie=new Movie(data[i]);
             movie.save();
        }
      }

    });
```